# Prevent exit application by closing 1 of the 2 frames

Tags: java, processing

I want a simple program that can load other programs.
So far, it works great, except that if I close one frame that all the frames get closed (exit with exit code 0). How can I prevent this from happening?

```
public class AllSketches extends PApplet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main("forMyself.AllSketches", args);
    }

    // here all sketches we want
    P5_BackFaceCulling backFaceCulling;

    public void setup() {

    }

    public void draw() {

    }

    public void keyPressed() {
        if (key == '1') {
            // this creates a new window,
            // but when I close it then both windows gets closed!
          backFaceCulling = new P5_BackFaceCulling();
          backFaceCulling.main(new String[]{});

          Frame f = backFaceCulling.getFrame();

          if (f instanceof JFrame) {
              ((JFrame)f).setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
           }
        }
    }

}
```

To make it more clear:
If I close one of the 2 then the program exits.
What I want is that if I close the frame on the right that it closes only the frame on the right. (If I close the one on the left then I don't care about the behaviour).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the `setDefaultCloseOperation` of Jframe. You have:

```
DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Don't do anything; require the program to handle the operation in the windowClosing method of a registered WindowListener object.
HIDE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.
DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide and dispose the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.
EXIT_ON_CLOSE (defined in JFrame): Exit the application using the System exit method. Use this only in applications.
```

You may be using `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`. Try `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` instead.

Comment: I modified my question without seeing yours. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The sketch I loaded was with P3D.

therefor `getFrame()` was not returning a `JFrame` but some other kind of frame.